# Select an attribute with Xpath in a XML with namespace using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have a .Net config file with a NLog node inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets async="true">
      <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="path to file" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="c,f" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

I'm trying to change the `target`'s `fileName` value using Powershell.

I'm using this code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace) # $namespace is `http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd`
$values = $xml.selectNodes($xpath, $ns)
```

My XPath expression is `//ns:nlog/ns:targets/ns:target[@ns:name='f']/@ns:fileName`

But $values always has 0 results.

Any idea ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XML document, there is a *default namespace*:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
```

Descendant elements are then implicitly prefixed with this namespace. However, [attributes do not take on a default namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#uniqAttrs). In other words, the attribute in your input XML is *not* called `ns:fileName`, but only `fileName`. The same applies to the `name` attribute.

```
//ns:nlog/ns:targets/ns:target[@name='f']/@fileName
```

Depending on the structure of your XML (and its predictability) you might want to shorten the expression to

```
//ns:target[@name='f']/@fileName
```

---

To make your intial XPath expression work, the input XML would have to look like:

```
<targets xmlns:ns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" async="true">
  <target xsi:type="File" ns:name="f" ns:fileName="path to file" />
</targets>
```