# Select XML nodes from a namespace using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, namespaces, selectsinglenode

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<userSettings>
  <setting name="TelephonyServerHost">
    <value>sipserver.domain.local</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SipServerFqdn">
    <value>sipserver.domain.local</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="WebServicesHost">
    <value>websvc.domain.local</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="KMSettings">
    <value>
      <KMIndexSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <AutoIndexEnabled>false</AutoIndexEnabled>
     </KMIndexSettings>
    </value>
  </setting>
</userSettings>
```

I am able to retrieve the values of the setting elements using xpath but I cannot figure out the correct syntax for querying the AutoIndexEnabled element using the namespace.

This works as expected for reading the KMSettings or other nodes which do not have a namespace:

```
$xml = New-Object -TypeName 'System.XML.XMLDocument'
$xml.Load($xmlFilePath)
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//userSettings/setting[@name='KMSettings']")
```

But I can't figure out the syntax on how to query the AutoIndexEnabled element.

Comment: I'm not a PowerShell user, so won't be able to help with the PowerShell specific syntax, but in terms the xml, the AutoIndexEnabled element is within the xsi namespace, therefore you should use PowerShell's facilities to access the namespace and then the nodes within that namespace. Doing a quick search I've found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566269/select-an-attribute-with-xpath-in-a-xml-with-namespace-using-powershell) which looks like matches your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. The namespaces doesn't matter here because your xml-sample doesn't contain prefixed elements or a default namespace. You can access the element like this:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//AutoIndexEnabled")
```

or

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//setting[@name='KMSettings']//AutoIndexEnabled")
```

Output:

```
#text
-----
false

PS> $xml.SelectNodes("//AutoIndexEnabled").InnerText
false
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused with the xpath syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Within PowerShell you can access XML nodes like properties, so this works:

```
($xml.DocumentElement.setting | ? name -eq 'KMSettings').value.KMIndexSettings.AutoIndexEnabled
```

And here is a working XPATH solution:

```
[string]$xpath="//userSettings/setting[@name='KMSettings']/value/KMIndexSettings/AutoIndexEnabled"       
$xml.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
```

Comment: Did the sample change? I can't see any SOAP-namespace and you're not even using it in your xpath.. :S

Comment: Upps, you are right @FrodeF. I just copied the solution from a previous answer. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thanks, your xpath helped.

Answer (score 0):

I this particular example, how would you select the value of the attribute with name "xmlns:xsi"?

```
<value>
  <KMIndexSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ... >
    <AutoIndexEnabled>false</AutoIndexEnabled>
 </KMIndexSettings>
</value>
```

I would expect to see the output: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

This is what I'm trying.The colon is throwing off my script. I get the following error: "Unexpected token ':id' in expression or statement."

```
([xml](gc $files[$i])).contentHaul.constant.typedValue.value.a:id
```